# Using a variable to look for a value. JSON Alexa skill

Tags: json, variables, alexa-skills-kit

Hi im making a simple Alexa skill that asks for a monster name and tells you the speed

I ask the user for a monster name, the user's monster name then is stored in: **handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.name.value**

and I save it to variable **monster** (code below) so it saves the name given by the user.

I also have a file called **typecharts**, there i got numbers relative to monsters speed.

**typecharts file:**

```
module.exports = {

    Werewolf: '60',
    Alien: "98",
    Herb: "10",
};
```

so variable **monster** (code below) prints the name given by the user correctly, the problem is this:

- I know how to call the number values  in that file **(typecharts)** like *Werewolf* or *Alien* for alexa to speak by doing this: **.speak(typecharts.Alien)** and it says **98**,
- but i need to place the variable that stores the name of the monters the user given so it looks for the monster we want, something like this **.speak(typecharts.*variable monster here*)** so she looks for typecharts.whathevertheusersaid, alien merewolf or herb.

I tried by creating this variable const **spe = (typecharts.monster)** but it fails because it doesn't look for the name the user said *(saved at "monster" variable)*, it looks for "monster" instead, not the name inside variable, ¿how can i make it look for the text stored at monster?.

**CODE TO FIX:**

```
    canHandle(handlerInput) {

        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'CompareIntent';
                            },

    handle(handlerInput) {

        const monster = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.name.value
        const spe = (typecharts.monster) // <- i need to fix this to do what i need.

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder

            .speak("you said "+ monster +" with speed " + spe ) // <- alexa speech output
            .reprompt("tell me more")
            .getResponse();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bracket syntax to access object keys with a variable (otherwise, it will try to find a key named "monster", which you don't have).

```
handle(handlerInput) {

    const monster = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.name.value
    const spe = typecharts[monster]

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder

        .speak("you said "+ monster +" with speed " + spe ) // <- alexa speech output
        .reprompt("tell me more")
        .getResponse();

}
```

Keep in mind to handle the case where the monster is not found, i.e.

```
if (!spe) { ... } else { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift deploy :) and for the tip!